# How do I create a batch script that creates a task for a specific user in the Active Directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the code I currently have, but all it does is create the task for me rather than that user.

```
@echo off
echo Enter Computer Name: 
set /p compname=

schtasks.exe /create /sc once /tn defrag /tr "\\compname\C$Windows\system32\defrag.exe c:" /st 14:33:00 
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For it to run as that user you need to specify both username and password.

```
schtasks.exe /create /?

[snip]
    /U           username          Specifies the user context under
                                   which the command should execute.

    /P           password          Specifies the password for the given
                                   user context.
[snip]
```

So, for user 'jsmith', with password 'password1', your command will end up looking something like:

```
schtasks.exe /create /u jsmith /p password1 /sc once /tn defrag /tr "\\compname\C$Windows\system32\defrag.exe c:" /st 14:33:00
```